# Why showing two audio players in chrome?

Tags: html, audio

I want to add background audio in my website. I have already put one audio player but it shows two audio player instead of one in chrome. In firefox it shows only one.

Can anyone guide me to solve this issue? Also currently there is no mute/unmute button in player. I want to put a mute/unmute button with player.

Code I am using is as below:

```
<audio autoplay="true" controls="" src="XXXXXXXXXXX" preload="auto"></audio>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include the HTML code you are using to add the audio player without it is impossible to give an answer.

Comment: Now I have made some changes in them code and its working fine for chrome. But Audio player appears in firefox and then goes invisible.